# SQL Server Delete Order for FKC?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a tree table that has foreign keys to self *(depth-unlimited parents and children)*. Given that SQL Server lacks the `CASCADE` *(within same table, loops)* support MySQL offers, I need to first order the IDs to delete before deleting them. I order them with a CTE from most-deletable *(no children)* to least-deletable *(top parents)*.

I want to throw this set of IDs to a `DELETE` but I need them deleted in the exact order I send them to SQLServer. Can this be done in a single query?

I could write a stored procedure to delete the records or just `DELETE` one by one with multiple queries from C#... but I'm wondering if this can be achieved in a simple `DELETE FROM WHERE IN` query? I have no clue if `DELETE` retains order of the `IN (...)` collection, because if it doesn't... the `FKC` will block it. *-- Coming from MySQL, never cared as they can cascade within the same table.*

Comment: I believe it deletes them in the order that the query plan tells it (but I could be wrong) I wouldn't count on the order in the IN string. You might have to just recursively delete the children in batches until they're all gone.

Comment: The constraints are checked at the end of the statement.Not after each row. So as long as you can delete them all in one statement there is no problem.#

Comment: According to the MSDN documentation: _When a TOP (n) clause is used with DELETE, the delete operation is performed on a random selection of n number of rows. If you have to use TOP to delete rows in a meaningful chronological order, you must use TOP together with ORDER BY in a subselect statement._ That indicates for me that the order is retained in the `in` statement. If you want to go 100% sure though, you could add something like top 100 percent to your custom table expression.

Comment: @MartinSmith So a `DELETE IN` would work as long as no lingering dependencies are left in the table when the constraint check is done? --- Well, post this comment as an answer, slap a link to it and I'll accept it.